# Plotly : Return custom hover data in callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to return a custom hover data from a callback to trigger some subsequent function.

This is a working code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

from dash import Dash, Input, Output
from dash import callback
from dash import dcc, html
import string
import random

#Some synthetic data
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(600,10),columns =['Band-'+str(i) for i in range(10)])
df['Label'] = np.random.randint(0,3,600)
df['Name'] = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase +
                             string.digits, k=7)) for i in range(600)]
```

So the dataframe looks like this

[image]

In the Dash part, when the user selects any of 0,1,2 from the dropdown, it draws a heatmap based on the first 10 columns. When I hover over the heatmap, it faithfully shows the custom hover data containing the "name". However , when I try to return this as hover data , it only contains x,y,z data ( see the print statement in the 2nd callback )

```
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown([0,1,2], 0, id="my_dropdown"),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id="my_picbox",
                        )
                    ],
                ),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(
                            id="my_picbox2",
                        )
                    ])
            ],
            style={"display": "flex"},
        ),
    ]
)

#First callback to draw heatmap based on dropdown choice
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="my_picbox", component_property="figure"),
    Input(component_id="my_dropdown", component_property="value")
)

def update_plot(choice):
    
    if choice is not None:
        
        # Select rows from the dataframe based on dropdown value

        sel_df = df[df['Label'] == choice]
        sel_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        
        # This generates an array of the custom hover data with the
        # same dimensions as array img generated below

        cells = np.array(sel_df['Name'])
        hover_cell = np.vstack([cells]*10).T
        img = np.array(sel_df[['Band-'+str(i) for i in range(10)]])
        
        fig = px.imshow(img,
                        height =600,
                        width = 800,
                        y = sel_df.index,
                        x = ['Band-'+str(i) for i in range(10)],
                        color_continuous_scale = 'Reds')
        
        fig.update_xaxes(tickangle= 90) 
        
        fig.update(data=[{'customdata': np.dstack((hover_cell, img)),
                        'hovertemplate': '%{y}<br>%{x}<br>%{customdata[0]}<br>%{customdata[1]:0.3f}'}])
        
                
    return fig

# Second callback to print hover data
@app.callback(
     Output(component_id='my_picbox2', component_property='figure'),
     Input(component_id='my_picbox', component_property='hoverData')
)

def show_sample(hover_data):
    
    disp_imgs = 10
    imgs = np.empty((disp_imgs,100,24),)
    imgs[:]= np.nan
    
    if hover_data:
        print(hover_data['points'][0])
    fig = px.imshow(imgs[:, :, :],
            binary_string=False,
            zmin=0,
            zmax=1,
            facet_col=0,
            aspect = 'auto',
            facet_col_wrap = 5,
            facet_row_spacing = 0)
       
    return fig
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8059)
```

[image]

```
{'curveNumber': 0, 'x': 'Band-9', 'y': 108, 'z': 0.5140773896703603, 'bbox': {'x0': 651.4, 'x1': 714, 'y0': 347.53, 'y1': 349.78}}
{'curveNumber': 0, 'x': 'Band-9', 'y': 100, 'z': 0.07920775127084145, 'bbox': {'x0': 651.4, 'x1': 714, 'y0': 329.49, 'y1': 331.75}}
{'curveNumber': 0, 'x': 'Band-8', 'y': 97, 'z': 0.7880534584628361, 'bbox': {'x0': 588.8, 'x1': 651.4, 'y0': 322.73, 'y1': 324.98}}
{'curveNumber': 0, 'x': 'Band-7', 'y': 102, 'z': 0.15382653844436867, 'bbox': {'x0': 526.2, 'x1': 588.8, 'y0': 334, 'y1': 336.25}}
{'curveNumber': 0, 'x': 'Band-7', 'y': 105, 'z': 0.07720891051619971, 'bbox': {'x0': 526.2, 'x1': 588.8, 'y0': 340.76, 'y1': 343.02}}
```